# React - How to display only one instance of a dropdown component

Tags: reactjs

I have a custom dropdown component that contains different items depending on the caller, its connected to a state that toggles its visibility, to be able to render it i use this method

### Code

Dropdown.jsx

```js
const Dropdown = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.dropdown}> {children} </div>)};
```

Component1.jsx

```js
const Component1 = () => {
 return (
 .....
 {dropdownOpen && <Dropdown> ... </Dropdown>)
}
```

Component2.jsx

```js
const Component2 = () => {
 return (
 .....
 {dropdownOpen && <Dropdown> ... </Dropdown>)
}
```

the problem is whenever i click on any of the caller(button, icon ..etc) it shows dropdowns for all components bcz **dropdownOpen is true** (i use the same logic in different locations)

So how i render only one dropdown for that particular component without showing it for others

Comment: Could you add a little more code about how you are handling dropdown?

Comment: sorry i posted it using phone yesterday and forgot to edit and add code

Comment: *the problem is whenever i click on any of the caller* where is that button ? Is `dropdownOpen` the same state shared across components? From where it is being passed down ? Please attach more detailed code or add a codesandbox.io

Comment: It's one state passed from App.jsx to different components which leads to all dropdowns being showed whenever i click on any caller. Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-bird-smqz05?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: keeping the same state will obviously open both , create a separate state for each.

Comment: ty, i was wondering if there is a way we can do it with the same state, like target-rendering the dropdown depending on the caller